# Why is there horizontal scrollbar in this html page

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVMNzP

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas, Sans;
}
.spacer {
  height:100px;
}
#firstDiv {
  height:300px;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.nopadding {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div id="firstDiv" class="row row-eq-height" style="background-color:#ddaaee;">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding" style="background-color:#45aa78;">
        Col1
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding" style="background-color:#ccaa78;">
        Col2
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding" style="background-color:#45aa2b;">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 1</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 2</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 3</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 4</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am of the view that the entire content should fit completely on the screen.
I don't expect a horizontal bar in this scenario, I also want the list-group to fit in third column without any padding.

Please suggest code changes, or point out any mistake that I may have done.

Comment: try to fix the width size..

Comment: Please consider upvoting answers in case they are helpful to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve you should use containers i.e. either **container** or **container-fluid** which should be positioned outside of the row.

Other answers are partially correct because they are changing the way Bootstrap works.

The basic layout should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it was default margin in .row that was causing this overflow. fixed by removing margin in .row

Comment: @learningeek True, but that's also why some other Bootstrap elements play nice with each other. If you remove that margin you'll most likely run into other positioning problems later.

Comment: you have got valid point.
please suggest me then, how to fix this horizontal scrollbar thing without playing with row margin.

Comment: @learningeek First, start with a container as this is an initial point, then add a row (or multiple if you need to separate page sections by rows) and then add columns. Also, be aware that adding container within a container could cause additional problems.

Comment: Thanx @Agramer for sorting it out for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Is causing the element to be more wide than the window.

Answer (score 1):

you did't used "container-fluid"

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="row row-eq-height" style="background-color:#ddaaee;">
```

you have to use like below to remove **horizontal scrollbar**

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="container-fluid row-eq-height" style="background-color:#ddaaee;">
```

Comment: But it will affect when u use "row" in some other div. so u have to use "container-fluid" this is the proper way to use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding to have none!

```
.nopadding{
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.row {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

**Preview**

```css
body{font-family:Consolas,Sans;}
.spacer{height:100px;}
#firstDiv{height:300px;}
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.nopadding{
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
.row {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div id="firstDiv" class="row row-eq-height" style="background-color:#ddaaee;">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding" style="background-color:#45aa78;">
    Col1
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding" style="background-color:#ccaa78;">
    Col2
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 nopadding" style="background-color:#45aa2b;">
    <div class="list-group">
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 1</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 2</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 3</a>
     <a href="#" class="list-group-item">List Item 4</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow css

```
.row {
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

or else wrap the `row` elements with `<div class="container-fluid">` div

Ex:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">.... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wrapping in container-fluid didn't help. but removing  margin from .row worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use .row it needs to be inside .container so the margins don't do what they are doing in the pen. Also .col-*-* elements need to be inside .row - If you don't follow that structure you're going to have wacky margins.